# How to remove an item from an array using faker and lodash?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, lodash, faker

I'm making a datatable with random user information using faker.js and lodash. I want to remove a user with a button. Every user has a remove button. So I when a user press the remove button I want that row to be removed.

When I first made this datatable I was able to remove the user with index. But then I wanted to be able to sort the users with their firstname and lastname. So had to change the code. So now when I removed by index the wrong one got removed. I have been looking on lodash documentation and I think I can use _remove and or _filter but don't know how.

The Code:

```
<body>
   <div id="app">
       <p></p>
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <!--Rubriker för tabellkolummer-->
                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th><a @click="deffinerasortering('firstName')" class="button">Förnamn</a></th>
                   <th><a @click="deffinerasortering('lastName')" class="button">Efternamn</a></th>
                   <th>Telefonnummer</th>
                   <th>E-postadress</th>
                   <th>Behörighet</th>
                   <th></th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr v-for="(user,index) in sortedUsers">
                 <template v-if="user.uuid==edituuid">
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.uuid" class="input" disabled></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.firstName" class="input"></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.lastName" class="input"></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.phone" class="input"></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.email" class="input"></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.jobTitle" class="input"></td>
                     <td><button class="button" @click="uppdaterapost(user.uuid)">Spara</button>
                         <button class="button" @click="tabortrad(user.uuid)">Ta bort rad</button></td>
                 </template>
                 <template v-else>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.uuid" class="input" disabled></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.firstName" class="input" disabled></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.lastName" class="input" disabled></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.phone" class="input" disabled></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.email" class="input" disabled></td>
                     <td><input type="text" v-model="user.jobTitle" class="input" disabled></td>
                     <td><button class="button" @click="redigerapost(user.uuid)">Redigera</button>
                         <button class="button" @click="tabortrad(user.uuid)">Ta bort rad</button></td>
                 </template>
             </tr>
             <th></th>
             <th></th>
             <th></th>
             <th></th>
             <th></th>
             <th></th>
             <th><button class="button is-pulled-right" @click='laggtillrad(users)'>Lägg till en rad</button></th>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
   <script>
       faker.locale = "sv";
       //Skapar slumpmässiga användardata
       let randomusers = [];
       for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
           let uuid = faker.random.uuid().substring(0, 5);
           let firstName = faker.name.firstName();
           let lastName = faker.name.lastName();
           let phone = faker.phone.phoneNumber();
           let email = faker.internet.email();
           let jobTitle = faker.name.jobTitle();
           randomusers.push({ 'uuid': uuid, 'firstName': firstName, 'lastName': lastName, 'phone': phone, 'email': email, 'jobTitle': jobTitle });
       }
       new Vue({
           el: '#app',
           data: {
               users: randomusers,
               sortkey: 'firstName',
               sortorder: 'asc',
               edituuid: ''
           },
           methods: {
               //Uppdaterar redigering av posten
               uppdaterapost: function (vilketuuid) {
                   this.edituuid = '';
               },
               //Redigerar raden där användaren trycker på "Redigera" knappen och ersätts med en spara knapp
               redigerapost: function (vilketuuid) {
                   this.edituuid = vilketuuid;
               },
               //Deffinerar sortering 
               deffinerasortering: function (vilkensortering) {
                   if (this.sortkey == vilkensortering) {
                       if (this.sortorder == 'asc') {
                           this.sortorder = 'desc'//Skriv så att det visas en pil/upp när man sorterar
                       }
                       else {
                           this.sortorder = 'asc'
                       }
                   }
                   this.sortkey = vilkensortering;
               },
               //Lägger till en rad längst ner i tabellen
               laggtillrad: function (event) {
                   var nyrad = {
                       uuid: faker.random.uuid().substring(0, 5),
                       firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
                       lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
                       phone: faker.phone.phoneNumber(),
                       email: faker.internet.email(),
                       jobTitle: faker.name.jobTitle(),
                   };
                   this.users.push(nyrad)
               },
               //Tar bort raden där användaren trycker på "Ta bort" knappen
               tabortrad: function (vilketuuid) {
                       console.log();
                   },
               },
               computed: {
                   sortedUsers() {
                       // Sorterar efter vad som finns i sortkey och med sorteringsordningen som finns i sortorder
                       return _.orderBy(this.users, [this.sortkey], [this.sortorder]);
                   }
               }
           })
   </script>
</body>
```

What I want is the correct user information to be removed. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work by using the following code.

```
tabortrad: function (vilketuuid) {
                this.users = _.filter(this.users, function(o) { return o.uuid !== vilketuuid; });
            },
```

and I have also put a key on the v-for.

Answer (score 2):

First, put [`:key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) on the your `v-for` to avoid rendering optimisation errors. I think this is your main issue. In fact, the error is just in the DOM. You can confirm that with *Vue DevTools*.

Then, add a button to call a method that uses `uuid`. Use `lodash.remove` if you want:

```js
_.remove(array, function(n) {
  return n.uuid === uuid;
});
```

If you use `lodash`, I think you lose the reactivity on the array, so re-set the array with:

```js
this.$set(this.$data, 'users', newuserarray);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried to put what you wrote in my code but don't really know where. As I am really new to vue js only worked with it for about a week right now. Give some tip in which area. Thank you again :)

Comment: $set for asignation with reactivity https://vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-set
and :key for avoiding rendering optimisation error :https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State